# I have a simple problem which should return an integer whose count is odd in an array

Tags: javascript

```
function findOdd(A) {
  var distinctElements = [...new Set(A)];
  distinctElements.forEach(x => {
    var count = A.filter(y => y === x).length;
    if (count % 2 != 0) {
      return x;
    }
  });
}
```

I don't understand why program is still executing after return statement.

Comment: The `return` ends the *current* function, and the current function is the callback. `forEach` then just continues to the next element and executes the callback again.

Comment: What is `x` and `y` set to? Also, can you provide some example input and outputs to your function?

Comment: You need to understand function scopes in javascript first. You are returning inside a child function.

Comment: You probably want find()

Comment: can you add a call of the function and the wanted result?

Answer (score 1):

Your `return` statement is being executed within a scope.

Try replacing the function with:

```js
function findOdd(A) {
    var distinctElements = [...new Set(A)];
    for (x of distinctElements) {
        var count = A.filter(y => y === x).length;
        if (count % 2 != 0) {
            return x;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should `return` out of the `forEach` after assigning a value to `out` to maintain the behavior of the original program.